Elderly African man faces resistance in attempts to get educated
I've been watching this movie at school but the I have no clue what it is and the teacher has now gone on holiday so it's impossible to ask her and no one else knows. I only have watched it from about 43 mins in so I have no clue what happens in the beginning.
It's about this African Man who is about 84 who fought for Africa against the British, his family ends up dying to the hands of them in front of the old man (You see that in a flash-back scene thing). This guy wants to be educated so he goes to the local Primary School where the headteacher takes him in. Most people are against it though and in the end the headteacher ends up being transferred to somewhere else and the school throw cups, rocks anything they can when the new headteacher arrives. The press and the local community end up hounding the school and the old man and headteacher with threats and attacking their school and homes.
I think the old man's name is Manuke (Or how ever you spell it.)
Does anyone know the name of this movie?

I think you're looking for the The First Grader (2010)
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0790663/
From imdb:

The true story of an 84 year-old Kenyan villager and ex Mau Mau freedom fighter who fights for his right to go to school for the first time to get the education he could never afford.


Yes that is perfect thank you, I did not realize it was a true story though :)

@Skye yeah, I've never heard of this movie before today but it looks very interesting. I'll have to watch it.

It's a bit odd but ok, You might like it if you like things like this.
